# Understanding a real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x\in(0,1]$ show that there is a unique sequence $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ with the following properties:

- $\alpha_i=0$ or $1$
- $\alpha_1=1$ for infinitely many $i\in \textbf{N}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha_i}{2^{i}}=x$

What is this asking? Please refrain from answers, I just want to know what the problem is asking and where I should begin?

Comment: It is asking to show there there is a unique sequence $(a_n)$ of $0$'s and/or $1$'s, with infinitely many $1$'s, such that $x=\sum \frac{a_i}{2^i}$. So the sequence $1,0,1,1,0,0,0,\dots$ (the rest all $0$'s) is not allowed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10438/discussion-between-crypto-and-andre-nicolas)

Comment: I prefer to avoid chat. But I will delete my previous comments, suggest you do the same, and then there will be room for more questions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I think I'm starting to have some understanding of the problem. It's saying that every number in that range has a unique binary representation. Correct? So when you divided something by 2, the remainder is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes. The uniqueness will be fairly short. Take two such sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, and let $k$ be the first place where they differ, say $a_k=0$ and $b_k=1$. Show that $\sum\frac{a_i}{2^i}\lt \sum \frac{b_i}{2^i}$. Existence is a bit more time consuming. Here is a very rough beginning. Let $a_1=1$ if $x\ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $0$ otherwise. Now if you can figure out how to describe $a_2$, you will be on your way.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking to show that every number in the unit interval has a unique binary representation, but there is a switcheroo: all the numbers that would ordinarily terminate by ending in an infinite run of zeros must end in an infinite run of ones instead.  $0$ is excluded for the same reason that $1$ is excluded in the ordinary version of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this only confused me more. i'll just think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to show that every number in $(0, 1]$ can be written in a way that satisfies all three conditions, and that there is only one such way.

It may be helpful to consider an analogue that you will be familiar with. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. There is a unique sequence $n_0, n_1, \dots$ with the following properties:

- $n_i \in \{0, \dots, 9\}$,
- $n_i = 0$ for infinitely many $i$, and
- $n = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}n_i10^i$.

This is just one way of expressing the fact that any non-negative integer has a unique base $10$ expansion.